# Rendering Component Like HTML

Tags: react-native

Basically I want to render a component like float left behavior in HTML. So the component will rendered horizontally (make a row) until there is no enough space and render it under the previous row.

`const {card,insideCard} = styles;
        return(
            <View style={card}>
                <View style={insideCard}/>
                <View style={insideCard}/>
                <View style={insideCard}/>
                <View style={insideCard}/>
            </View>
        );`

and the style

`card:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'#0000ff',
        margin:5,
        flexDirection:'row',
    },
    insideCard:{
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        backgroundColor:'#000000',
        margin:10
    }`

when I render it the forth View tag will be cut in half.
Is there a way to render it like HTML? So the forth view will render downside automatically?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply `flexWrap: 'wrap'` to your `card` style. If you want to deal with alignment, play around with `justifyContent: 'center'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set flexWrap property to card view:

```
card:{
        flex:1,
        flexWrap:'wrap',
        backgroundColor:'#0000ff',
        margin:5,
        flexDirection:'row',
    },
```